# Dynamically adjust child and parent div height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that is embedding another html file in it, it look like this:

[image: Image of website]

If I click on the the arrow, the inner webpage is expanded to show its contents like this:

[image: Image of expanded element]

The problem is, I get two scroll bars (an inner and the regular website scrollbar). I only want the outer scrollbar (the regular website scrollbar). So I want my parent and child div height to dynamically grow and I am having trouble figuring out how. I tried all the `overflow`properties. But I could have been setting them wrong.

I am changing my inner div like so:

```
document.getElementById("versionsContent").innerHTML = '<object class="versionsContent" type="text/html" data="TEST-iPhoneTGxD22SmokeTest.html" width="800px" style="float:left"/>';
```

My HTML definition of this div is:

```
        <div id="versionsContent" class="versionsContent">
            <object class="versionsContent" type="text/html" data="TEST-iPhoneTGxD22SmokeTest.html" width="800px"/>
        </div>
```

And my relevant CSS definitions are:

```
body
{
 background-color: CCCCCC;
}
.versionsContent
{
 font: 18pt Arial,Helvetica !important;
 font-weight: 30 !important;
 background-color: 444444 !important;
 overflow: hidden;
 min-height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 align-content: center;
 padding: 35px !important;
 width: 95%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an iframe to show html content. Then, use javascript to set the iframe's height according to its content.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function setSize(id){
    var newheight;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
}
</script>

<iframe src="TEST-iPhoneTGxD22SmokeTest.html" width="800px" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="setSize('iframe1');"></iframe>
```